# Combinatorics question. Bit stuck.

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

Why can't there exist 5 5-digit binary numbers such that each pair has 1 or 2 digits in common?

Another way to state the condition is that any pair has either 3 or 4 digits that are different.

Comment: What did you try? What are your thoughts? How do you know the result holds?

Comment: *I'll delete the question*... Why?

Comment: **WHY?** $ $ $ $

Comment: Please stop defacing the question.

Comment: but now that it's up, I'm interested. It's not just for the asker.

Comment: bob, as mezhang says, this website is for everyone to benefit from. You've asked a good question, and gotten a good answer. Deleting (or, as you've been doing, *defacing*) the question eliminates the helpfulness to others. Please, **don't do it again**, or the moderators may lock the post.

Answer (score 4):

Assume we have found 5 such numbers $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$. We can generate new solutions by exclusively or'ing each one with any constant we choose, and by picking $a_1$ we can get a solution where one of the five numbers is $0$.

Now, each other number must have either 3 or 4 $1's$ in to satisfy the conditions. Note that any pair of 5 bit numbers with 4 $1's$ would share 3 bits in common, so at most one of the other 4 numbers has 4 $1's$. Thus we have at least 3 numbers with only 3 $1's$. Since there are only 5 bits, at least one pair of these must share a $0$, but that would mean they also share two of the $1's$. Hence this set cannot satisfy the requirements, and thus no such set exists.